# One edge intersects with exactly one vertex of the minimum cardinality vertex cover of a bipartite graph.

Tags: graph-theory

I know the statement is not true if the graph is not bipartite, but I do not know how to prove it if the graph is bipartite.

To make my question clearer, I would like to prove **Suppose graph $G = (V,E)$ is bipartite and a minimum cardinality vertex cover $C$ in $G$. Then every edge $e \in E$ is adjacent to exactly one vertex of $C$.**

I tried to prove by contradiction, suppose I have an edge $(u,v)$ with $u$ and $v$ both belongs to $C$, then it seems I need to show $C-{u}$ or $C-{v}$ is still a vertex cover.

Comment: If your question is to show that it is true for all edges, this is wrong, take two stars with the center linked by an edge. The minimal vertex cover comprises the two centers, but these two vertices are the extremities of an edge. If your question is to show (as in your title) that there is at least one such edge, then it is trivial...

Comment: Nice counter-example. Thank you!